# is my code thread-safe ? how to achieve thread safety in this if not?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections, thread-safety

I was asked a question in an interview..
What to do If I want to store values in map like this :

```
key_1 --> value 1
key_2 --> value 2
key_1 --> value 3
```

Here if we assume both key and value is in string then we should take map like this..

```
Map<String,List<String>> m1 = new HashMap();
```

Then I was asked what if you want to achieve thread safety? Then I said we can take **ConcurrentHashMap** for this purpose..they said ok..

Then they asked are value I mean List is threadsafe ? 
Ex.

```
t1.get("key_1").put("value_4");    
t2.get("key_1").put("value_5");
```

Here, assume both threads t1 and t2 are running in parallel. So if that `List<String>` i mean value inside **ConcurrentHashMap** is Thread-Safe ? If yes then how ? and if No then how to achieve that ??

Comment: It depends on the implementation of List.

Comment: Values stored in a ConcurrentHashMap are no more or less thread safe than those values outside the map.

Comment: @AndyTurner ,can you please explain in detail ? I did not get you.Sorry for that.

Comment: The operations you do on the Map will be thread-safe, i.e. get() and put() and containsKey(). But once you've fetched the value [which is a list in your case], thread-safety to the modifications pertaining to that particular list elements will depend entirely on the implementation of the list object [or any other java object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is Thread Safe Data Structure. If you use `List<String>`(which is Not thread safe) in value of `ConcurrentHashMap` then the `List` is not Thread safe because two thread can safe the reference of list and later modify it parallel.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a thread safe means Its operations like `put` and `putAll` e.t.c are thread safe.It does't mean the data structure which you are using as its value also become Thread safe.

**How to achieve that ?**

- Use Thread Safe `List<String>` like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`  as value in your `ConcurrentHashMap`.
- Make customize `List` and make their all methods `Synchronized`.
- Convert non-thread safe `List` to Thread safe `List` by passing in `Collections.synchronizedList(non-Thread safelist)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I said we can take ConcurrentHashMap for this purpose..they said ok..

Maybe it's OK, maybe not.  It depends on whether there is any special relationship between key_1 and key_2.

Suppose that one thread stores a new value for key_1, and then just before it can store a related value for key_2, its time slice ends. Another thread then examines the values of key_1 and key_2 while the first thread is suspended. It sees the new value for key_1, but it sees the *old* value for key_2.

Does it matter at that point that the first thread was only half-way done updating the two keys?

Plugging in a `ConcurrentHashMap` will ensure that the map data structure itself will not do anything funny or wrong in a multi-threaded application, but if the application depends on those two keys always being updated together, then you're still going to need some kind of explicit locking to ensure that they always are updated together.